# Does the snap-on ct350 impact wrench have an electric brake?

Tags: tools, tool-identification

[image]

Such as described in this video: https://youtu.be/u3tl2CEEUTI?t=318

Basically I need to know if it'll stop immediately when I let off the trigger or if it'll keep going like an air or corded impact. Thanks!

Comment: Every electric impact i have used has an electric brake or other mechanism that stops it from tuning when you let off the trigger.

Comment: I have an older (5+ years) 18v Snap-On cordless and it doesn't have an electric brake.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Snap-Ons' specification sheet there is no mention of a brake. I can only imagine that if they took the time to design it in to the tool they would mention it in the literature or specifications. I have noticed on my battery powered tools they do stop turning fairly soon after the trigger is released. It feels more of an effect of the gear reduction than an internal brake. They do stop much faster than an air powered tool which can coast for a few seconds while the air bleed out of the air-motor.